# Is there a memory cache for SQLite in Android and how to release or clear it?

Tags: android, sqlite

Firstly, I create a database called "mydb" in my Android app:

```
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context, "mydb", null, 1);//DBHelper is my custom class
```

And write some data into it's table:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
db.execSQL("insert into mytable(name, text) values ('allen','hello')");
```

Here, everything is ok. But then, i delete this database manually not by programming, with a software "R.E. explore" (Certainly on a rooted device).

Then, in my code, i read this table of the database. What is astonishing is that i still could get the data I stored.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("mytable", new String[]{"name","text"}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Why?

Comment: I ever tried the following methods, but do not work.
SQLiteDatabase.releaseMemory();

This could work:
db.close();
db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

But i don't want to solve it by this way. I wonder if there is a memory cache, and i want to clear this, and to let android system to reload data from database and get updated data.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from the Android Developers reference website:

> Once opened successfully, **the database is cached**, so you can call
>   this method every time you need to write to the database. (Make sure
>   to call close() when you no longer need the database.)

This is from the description of the `getWritableDatabase()` method, however both `getReadableDatabase()` and `getWritableDatabase()` return basically the same object for reading the database.

Please note that you should use `getWritableDatabase()` if you want to persist the changes you make to the database on the device's internal memory. Otherwise they will be valid only for the duration of the application's runtime and will be discarded once the app is closed. If you wish to delete the database completely, you should call the SQLiteDatabase's `close()` method in order to invalidate the cache.

Comment: Thanks. Furthermore, is there a way to invalidate the cache without calling SQLiteDatabase's close() method?

Comment: You have several non-programmatic options, like force-closing the app or restarting the device. If you wish to delete a database, you must close any pre-existing SQLiteDatabase objects pointing to its cache, then call the static SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(file) method to delete it. Seems pretty straightforward to me...

Comment: Furthermore, notice that close() is a synchronized method, meaning that calling close() on an open connection will close any other valid SQLiteDatabase object you have. If you fear that your database may be gone during runtime, for some reason, group your database calls together and get a new readable/writable object every time you need to communicate with the database. This is not recommended as it will hurt performance, but do it if you must.

Answer (score 0):

use `SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(File file)` API to delete the database

Deletes a database including its journal file and other auxiliary files that may have been created by the database engine.

Make sure you have closed all the connections that are open.

In case you are not able to do that,
just cal the deleteDatabase followed by kill process.. - not recommended

Answer (score -1):

> You need to delete the app from your phone then install again