# Do DBs used for android apps cache in memory?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

Normally when using an SQL database (MySQL, MS-SQL etc) the database caches as much as possible in memory for performance.
When using a database for an android app e.g sqlite does it also uses the same/similar approach to caching? Does it cache as much as possible in memory or for the android environment does it go to SD for each query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a memory cache for SQLite in Android and how to release or clear it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290966/is-there-a-memory-cache-for-sqlite-in-android-and-how-to-release-or-clear-it)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite caches as much as you have configured with [PRAGMA cache_size](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size), or 2000 pages by default.